# Execution time of query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

When executing the code, Neo4j itself writes `Started streaming 523565 records after 1 ms and completed after 3079 ms, displaying first 1000 rows`. But if you time the query output, it turns out more than 30 seconds. How to make it so that the correct query output time is displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timings that are reported are from the perspective of the neo4j *server*.

But your *client* (e.g., the Neo4j Browser) can take a long time to process the results (if it is very large) before presenting the results to you. That accounts for the difference between the reported timing and what you experience. And the amount of time taken by the client totally depends on what the client does with the results, its implementation, the underlying platform, and how everything is configured.

Neo4j clients do not generally report total client processing time. For example, the Browser does not report such statistics, as far as I can tell.